# Intersection of minimal seperators

Tags: graph-theory

Let $S_1$ and $S_2$ be two minimal separators of a graph $G$ such that $S_1\cap S_2 \neq \phi$. Then is it true that $S_1 \cap S_2$ is also a minimal seperator.

Answer (score 1):

No it's not if $S_1\neq S_2 $. Go to the definition of Minimal Seperator. S is a minimal seperator of $G$ if there is no vertex seperator $P$ such that $P\subset S$. If $S_1\cap S_2 $ was a minimal seperator, then $S_1$ and $S_2$ would not be minimal, as they have a subset which is a vertex seperator. Then the only option for $S_1\cap S_2 $ to be a minimal seperator is that, $S_1= S_2 $.

Note: I had to consider the situation $S_1 = S_2$ as you didn't state that they were different minimal seperator of G.

Comment: Here I am talking about two different minimal separators. In general we can find two different minimal separators with non empty intersection.

Comment: @Gold Then, the intersection of those two cannot be a minimal seperator as I stated in the answer.

Comment: Intersection may be minimal for some other pair of vertices.
Definition of minimal separator says that it is a set of vertices $S$ for which there exist non adjacent vertices $a$ , $b$ such that $a$ & $b$ belongs to distinct connected components after removing vertices in $S$, and no proper subset of $S$ is an $a,b$ separator.

Comment: @Gold No it can't. 

" and no proper subset of S is an a,b separator." 

This is the key sentence. Intersection of those two sets is a subset of both. If it was a minimal seperator, than those two would not be minimal as they both have a subset which seperates G into two pairs. 

I mean, of course an intersection of two vertices can be a minimal seperator, and it is indeed. But making it minimal is that, there's no other subset of it which seperates G.

Answer (score 0):

Here to answer the question but mainly correct to [Zafer](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/98237/zafer-sernikli)'s answer.
A minimal separator can be strictly a subset of another minimal separator. Some paper stating as such are:

1. "Listing all potential maximal cliques of a graph" by Vincent Bouchitte and Ioan Todinca stating:

> Unlike the minimal separators, a potential maximal clique $\Omega'$ cannot be strictly included in another potential maximal clique $\Omega$.

2. "Finding Optimal Tree Decompositions" by Tuukka Korhonen

> Note that a
> minimal separator can be a subset of another minimal separator.

An example of such two separators can be seen in the following graph:

```
  a 
 / \
b   c - d
 \ /
  f
```

Here $\{b,c\}$ is a minimal *af*-separator and $\{c\}$ is a minimal *bd*-separator but one is strictly a subset of the other.

Now to answer the question.
If $S_1$ is strictly a subset of $S_2$ then the answer would be yes.
if $S_1$ is not strictly a subset of $S_2$, $S_1 \ne S_2$ and $S_1 \cap S_2 \ne \emptyset$; $S_1 \cap S_2$ can possible be and can possibly not be a minimal separator.

- Example of $S_1 \cap S_2$ being a minimal separator

  ```
        a
       / \
      c   d
     / \ / \
    e   f-g h
     \ / \ /
      j   k
       \ /
        l
  ```

  Here $\{c,f,k\}$ is a minimal *jd*-separator, $\{j, f, k\}$ is a minimal *ck*-separator and $\{f\}$ is a minimal *ag*-separator.
- Example of $S_1 \cap S_2$ not being a minimal separator, same as before without the vertex $g$.

  ```
        a
       / \
      c   d
     / \ / \
    e   f   h
     \ / \ /
      j   k
       \ /
        l
  ```

  Here $\{f\}$ is not a minimal separator.